# how to set $interval instead of timeout in Protractor Tests

Tags: javascript, ios, protractor, appium

I am working on iOS Hybrid app automation using `appium` and `Protractor`. I am using the timeout in my **config.js** file but getting the errors: Below are my **config.js** and **spec.js** file.

Kindly advise on how to use $interval instead of timeout.

**Config.js:**

exports.config = {
     allScriptsTimeout: 30000 ,
     getPageTimeout: 30000 ,
     ignoreSynchronization: true ,
     seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',

```
 specs: ['PageObjectSpec.js'],

 capabilities: {
     browserName: 'iOS' ,
    'appium-version':'1.3.4',
     platformName:'iOS'   ,
     platformVersion: 7.1 ,
     deviceName:'iPhone' ,
     autoWebview:true , 
    },
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000',   
 jasmineNodeOpts: {showColors: true, defaultTimeoutInterval:60000} ,
 onPrepare: function() {
 browser.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60000);
  }, 
};
```

**Spec.js file::**

```
'use strict';
describe('Abbvie app test', function() 

{
 var userName = browser.element(by.model('credentials.username'));  
 var passwd = browser.element(by.model('credentials.password'));
 var signin = browser.element(by.buttonText('Sign In'));
it('Login Page test', function()
 {
 userName.click();
 //userName.sendKeys(name)

 passwd.click();
 //passwd.sendKeys(pass)
signin.click();

}, 60000);
});
```

**Protractor Log:**Using the selenium server at

```
http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
The last active task was: 
Protractor.waitForAngular()
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:345:15)
    at [object Object].Protractor.executeAsyncScript_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:251:26)
    at [object Object].Protractor.waitForAngular (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:274:15)
    at [object Object].getWebElements (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:136:19)
    at [object Object].getWebElements (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:669:31)
    at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:391:28)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as click] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:77:19)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as click] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:698:11)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/qualcomm/Desktop/ProtractorTest/PageObjectSpec.js:13:11)
F

Failures:

  1) Abbvie app test Login Page test
   Message:
     timeout: timed out after 60000 msec waiting for spec to complete
   Stacktrace:
     undefined

Finished in 65.404 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] iOS #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

Kindly request your suggestions.
Thanks,

Comment: what angular version is used in your app? $interval is not available in older versions. waitForAngular is blocked till there are no more $http and $timeout running. i see you used in the exports.config the ignoreSynchronization=true; but if there is a waitForAngular timeout after 60+sec, it is obviously not set to true. i use ignoreSynchronization=true; in before blocks and do manual synchronization as i sadly need to use angualar in version 1.07

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't actually possible to use `$interval` instead of the default `timeout` parameters in your `config.js` file.

I'm guessing that the reason you're asking is because the Protractor docs recommend using `$interval` instead of `$timeout` in your Angular app if you're having timeout issues. This isn't something that needs to change in your Protractor test; it's something that needs to change in *the app itself*.

Your own files look fine.

Your error is a little strange. Talk to the app developers and see if they can find a `$http` or `$timeout` that isn't coming back. Also make sure the page loads as it says it should; check your developer console for errors, your Network tab for pending requests, and in general make sure everything is in place.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Isaac Lyman for the wonderful explanations!!,   Yes, you are right, I was asking because protractor docs recommend using $interval instead of time-out.